# Can't output my list

Tags: c, list, output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista
{
    char instrumento;
    char *nota;
    int inst;
    struct lista *prox;
}melodia;/*com typdef basta usar t_melodia não é preciso usar struct melodia*/



melodia *inicio, *fim; ///dois apontadores para definir o inico e o fim da lista

void inserir_inicio(char *v)
{
    if(inicio==NULL)
    {
        inicio = malloc(sizeof(melodia));
        inicio->nota = v;///nota fica com o valor recebido
        inicio->prox = NULL;///colocamos o prox para NULL
        fim = inicio;
    }
    else
    {
        melodia *temp = malloc(sizeof(melodia));
        temp->nota = v;
        temp->prox = inicio;
        inicio = temp; /// Colocamos o novo elemento no inicio
    }
    printf("Inserido no inicio\n");
}


void imprimir_lista()
{
    melodia *aux = inicio;
    printf("Lista:\n");
    while(aux!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", aux->nota);
        aux = aux->prox; /// proximo
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char n[100];
    while(i<5)
    {
    scanf("%s",n);
    inserir_inicio(n);
    i++;
    }
    imprimir_lista();
}
```

I think the problem is in my function imprimir_lista, i just can´t get it to print to the console the values i insert in the list....(the code is in portuguese if you are asking yourselves, and sorry for my english)

Comment: Your compiler should throw several warnings for that code. Fix those warnings first.

Comment: (1) at `inserir_inicio` : `inicio->nota = v;` : (`char nota;` , `char *v`) Different types.

Comment: Add some printout, run it under debugger, and you will understand everything by yourself in a few minutes

Comment: There is now a [beta stackoverflow site in portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com). You might like it :)

Comment: Getting there, pointers an such are new to me.So now i can print but it only prints the last thing i insert in the list

Comment: @user694733 Not if using a C99 compiler.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom My comment was made when there was obvious data type mismatch, which has since been edited out. I think you should rollback your tag edit, since it is not relevant to question. And this is not necessarily C99; single line comments have existed as compiler extension for a long time.

Comment: @user694733 It's relevant because the code generates syntax errors if compiled in standard ANSI C (C89) mode. If compiler extensions are used the question needs to be tagged with the compiler in question.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom My point is that *we don't know* if OP is using C99 compiler, or older compiler with extensions. So tag could be invalid. Only use C99 tag when question specifically asks about C99 standard, or OP has confirmed specific mode he/she is using. This is just a generic C question, and plain C tag will do. I am not trying to argue for arguments sake. Just trying to explain how tags should be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always passing the same address to `inserir_inicio()` (the `n`).

Every time you change the contents of `n` all the `nota` pointers in the list all point to the new contents.

You may need to copy the input to brand new objects.